# What does "it brings me back in a big way" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The description of [a game video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5KKdxXIUc9E):

> This is a weird one, as from a single player perspective it doesn't really seem to do that much that is new on a platform that seems to be absolutely dripping with behind the back runners. I mean, you've got your jumps, your slides, and a strange virtual control setup complete with all sorts of mention of physical buttons (Pressing R1, for instance). Where **it brings me back in a big way** is in the single device multiplayer mode, where two players grab either side of your device and go to town racing each other. I'm not sure I've seen that done before.

I've looked up *to bring sb back* [in the dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bring+back), but I'm not sure which (and if any) of these definitions fits the context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Saying **[something] brings me back** means it reminds you of something from the past, usually in the distant past.

If I see a movie on TV that I liked as a teenager I might say:

> This movie brings me back.

Now if I wanted to add emphasis (maybe the movie was one of the first movies I remember loving), I can say:

> This movie brings me back in a big way.

We can also use *take* instead of *bring*, as in:

> Seeing my old friend from high school really took me back.

Answer (score 1):

I generally agree with jonlink's explanation that "[something] brings [someone] back" means that the someone is *reminded* of times/situations from the past. But there is a problem with that meaning in this case.

The final sentence in the original paragraph says

> I'm not sure I've seen that done before.

This is a contradiction. If they have never seen this manner of controlling a game before, then it cannot "remind them" of past experience.

My analysis is that the reviewer is suggesting that the "weird" gameplay is off-putting.  They feel *pushed away* by the "strange virtual control setup". This makes them feel disinterested.  In contrast, the "single device multiplayer mode" is unusual (they have not seen that done before) and enjoyable. This feature brings them "back" towards the game --- meaning either that it metaphorically *pulls them to a more favorable opinion that they held earlier*, or literally that it *induces them to return to the game in order to play the game again*.

In general though, for something to "bring someone back" means that it reminds them so strongly of some past experience (often of a period of time) that they feel a subjective sense of being in that past situation again. Associated memories are refreshed. It's usually a positive emotion.